# What should I submit to my ISP for faster fix

Tags: internet, ping, isp, traceroute, tcpdump

I'm having a hard time using my Internet lately,  I'm wondering what kind of data collection / diagnostic of my network should I do before calling tech support. I'm doing a video capture of 'ping' running a few traceroute commands on video when connection is lost,  now I was thinking of doing a packet capture of around 50.000 packets,  is there anything else I could include and send it all to my ISP?

Comment: Redirect all your commands output to a text file. Wait one day, may be ISP is fixing your problem. Also you can get information of the nodes from traceroute command.

Comment: Even if you get all this information, a tier 1 tech isn't going to care much about it. They'll most likely take you into your router/modem to poke around with settings that don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

(Cannot comment yet, that is why I use the answer section)

Coming from the ISP industry, let me give a list of conceptual things that are useful to a) probe your ISP that the issue may be theirs* and b) provide useful information to route the issue internally**

1) Ping statistics are useful, but not to a single destination: Ping the immediate gateway (the first public IP on a `traceroute` is usually a nice point). Ping one of their DNSs, and 8.8.8.8 (Google's anycast DNS), ping a well-known site like www.apple.com (answers will come back from a content delivery network like Akamai, but that is fine)

Make short 30m tests of each destination at the same time, and provide the stats (does not help to give huge files with nothing interesting).

2) If your connection is ADSL or Cable, investigate if you can access diagnostics on the modem, and provide the SNR (signal-to-noise ratio) you see on you end. This may sound tricky, but if you get to the modem webpage I can help. If that SNR goes up or down during the day. That is a no-brainer for having the last-mile people check their stuff.

3) If your problem is bandwidth (you never lose connection, but sometimes it takes very long time to load even a simple web page, or you streaming services have hiccups): Make timed downloads of 2-5Mb files